# Como dividir uma string em tamanhos específicos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

Preciso dividir uma *string* em tamanho específico em JavaScript.

Sei que é possível usar o `join()` para transformar uma *string* em um *array* de letras:

```
'hello'.split('')
```

Porém, eu preciso de uma forma onde eu possa determinar o tamanho em que essa *string* vai ser quebrada.

Por exemplo, em PHP, temos a função `str_split()` onde você pode determinar o tamanho dessas *strings*.

No exemplo abaixo, quero dividir a *string* de 3 em 3.

```
str_split ('stackoverflow', 3)
```

Resultado:

```
[
    "sta",
    "cko",
    "ver",
    "flo",
    "w",
]
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso em JavaScript?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A maneira mais simples é:

```
'string'.match(/.{1,3}/g)
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qhjtc66/1/

A maneira sem Regex com um *loop* pode ser

```
const string = 'stackoverflow';
function spliter(str) {
    const chars = str.split('');
    let temp = [];
    let parts = [];
    for (let char of chars) {
        temp.push(char);
        if (temp.length == 3) {
            parts.push(temp.join(''));
            temp = [];
        }
    }
    if (temp.length) parts.push(temp.join(''));
    return parts;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/58ckfs2f/

Outra maneira, [integrando a resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146687/129) numa função seria:

```
const string = 'stackoverflow';

function spliter(str, nr) {
    const parts = [];
    for (let i = 0, length = str.length; i < length; i += nr) {
        parts.push(str.substring(i, i + nr));
    }
    return parts;
}

console.log(spliter(string, 3)); // ["sta", "cko", "ver", "flo", "w"]
console.log(spliter(string, 2)); // ["st", "ac", "ko", "ve", "rf", "lo", "w"]
console.log(spliter(string, 5)); // ["stack", "overf", "low"]
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p5611mnw/

---

## E qual é a mais rápida?

[Fiz um teste](https://jsfiddle.net/j4zoaja4/) onde corro a função 100.000 vezes e o resultado foi:

```
match 208 ms
pushloop 388 ms
substring 30 ms
```

Answer (score 9):

Sei que alguém fornecerá uma solução com RegEx, maseu prefiro algo assim (pode por em uma função para depois usar em uma só linha de forma mais simples que RegEx e provavelmente mais rápida.

```js
var str = 'stackoverflow';
var chunks = [];
for (var i = 0, charsLength = str.length; i < charsLength; i += 3) chunks.push(str.substring(i, i + 3));
for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) console.log(chunks[i]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Chunks.js).

Comment: Ah, é verdade! Tem como usar o `substring` também :D

Answer (score 4):

### [`string.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
console.log("stackoverflow".match(/.{1,3}/g));
```

### [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var str = 'stackoverflow';
var partes = 3
var pedacos = []

str.split('').map(function(v, i){
    var len = str.length - 1

    if ((i % partes == 0) && (len !== i))
      pedacos.push(str.substring(i, i + partes))
    
    if (len == i)
      pedacos.push(v)
})

console.log(pedacos)
```

### [`While`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) / [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
function extrairPedacos(str, n){
    var pedacos = []
    var i = 0
    
    while (i < str.length){
      (i % n == 0 ? pedacos.push(str.substring(i, i + n)) : i++)
      i++
    }
    return pedacos
}

console.log(extrairPedacos("stackoverflow", 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu sempre gosto de escrever os códigos em versões ES5/ES6, assim como suas versões imperativas e funcionais, então para contribuir aqui está um modelo ES6 um pouco funcional:

```
const splitStr = (str, size) => {
  const length = Math.ceil(str.length / size);
  return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => (i *= size, str.substring(i, i + size)))
}
```

Aproveitando do teste do Sergio, eu o [atualizei](https://jsfiddle.net/j4zoaja4/1/) com o modelo proposto aqui, o resultado acabou ficando:

```
match 328 ms
pushloop 260 ms
substring 31 ms
splitStr 110 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Há **n** formas de fazer, uma outra maneira seria assim:

```
var string = 'stackoverflow';

fnc = (str, num) => {
    var t=str.split(''), col = [];
    for(var i in t) {
       col.push(t[i]);
       if((i+1) % num === 0) {
         col.push('-');
       } 
    } 
  return col.join('').split('-').filter(e => e != "");
}

fnc(string, 3);
```